# Voluntary self identification of a disability form - should I discose my RA?

Tags: human-resources, security

I have rheumatoid arthritis.  Should I fill out the "voluntary self identification of a disability" form?  I have worked for this company over 20 years.  We do have a functional abilities test that you have to pass to be hired.  Needless to say it's been years since I took this test and I know I could not lift the 50lb to pass it anymore.  My fear is that if I fill out this form I'll somehow be required to take the test.

Comment: Would you get any benefit for filling out the form? If not, the word "voluntary" seems relevant.

Comment: This is an international forum. Don't assume the readers know what a "voluntary self identification of a disability" form is. You should at least [edit] a country tag into your question to better describe it.

Comment: I strongly suspect the OP is in the US and is talking about the [form required for companies that do business with the government](http://www.dol.gov/ofccp/regs/compliance/sec503/Voluntary_Self-Identification_of_Disability_CC-305_SD_Edit1.24.14.pdf). There's something similar for veterans. IIRC, there may also be a tax benefit for the company.

Comment: @peachie: Welcome to The Workplace! Please edit your question to clarify, as indicated in the comments. In particular, explain what a "voluntary self identification of a disability" form is, and explain what kind of "functional abilities test" your company uses, and what rules/consequences are attached to it.

Answer (score 4):

It's up to you if it's voluntary, and in your case I wouldn't. Why declare it when it's already on your record there? You would be doing yourself a disservice.

A good general life policy is 'Don't set yourself up to fail'. I see nothing positive from filling it out, and as you said, there is a potential, possibly career threatening negative.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: This answer assumes the "voluntary self identification of a disability" in the question refers to the form issued by the Office of Federal Contract Compliance Programs (OFCCP) in the United States. If OP edits to indicate otherwise, I'll delete this answer.*

The form "Voluntary self identification of a disability" you refer to is prescribed by the Office of Federal Contract Compliance Programs (OFCCP). Its purpose is to assess how many people with disabilities your employer employs, in order to raise the number of such people in employment.

It is part of a wider program, as explained for example in this blog entry: 
[OFCCP’s New Self-Identification Requirements](http://hudsonmann.com/ofccps-new-self-identification-requirements/). The blog also notes that filled-in forms must be stored to insure privacy:

> Recordkeeping
>
> Under OFCCP’s new regulations, completed self-identification forms
>   must be kept in a separate “data analysis file.”  This file can be
>   your HRIS or payroll system as long as the following requirements are
>   met:
>
> - disability-related data must be stored securely, apart from other personnel information, so that confidentiality is maintained
> - access to this data must be limited solely to contractor personnel who have a need to know the information for the purpose of complying
>     with OFCCP’s regulations
>
> The contractor must not keep the disability self-identification forms
>   in the employee’s medical file.

So, from a purely legal point of view you should have nothing to fear. In particular, the employer may not ask you about your disabilities because you filled in the form.

However, the employer *might* decide to ask you to re-do the functional abilities test, and might act on the results. Whether they can do that, and under what conditions, is a different (and mostly legal) question.